# Paragraph mode inside a math equation or reuse array-columns

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

My problem is that I want to reuse the spacing in a certain math equation like:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l@{\hspace{3mm}}c@{\hspace{3mm}}l}
... & := &  ... \\[4mm]
    & =: &  ...
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

This equation is followed by some text and then I want to repeat the above equation with the same spacings between array-columns. Is it possible? Out of the box I will get another spacing made by tex on the basis of the math symbols.

Perhaps it is possible to stick to one equation environment and insert the text in the equation. However `\mbox{...}` or `\text{...}` is not good enough because the text *must* show up in paragraph mode, left aligned w.r.t. the page.

W.r.t. the answer of Harish Kumar a MWE of my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
Example 1 (not ok):
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{l@{\hspace{3mm}}c@{\hspace{3mm}}l}
a \cdot b & := &  a \cdot \mathlarger{\llbracket\,} 0, \, b \mathlarger{\,\rrbracket} \\[4mm]
    & =: &  ...
\end{array}
\intertext{In the group this means that ... }
\begin{array}{l@{\hspace{3mm}}c@{\hspace{3mm}}l}
a & = &  b.
\end{array}
\end{align}
Example 2 (ok):
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{l@{\hspace{3mm}}c@{\hspace{3mm}}l}
a \cdot b & := &  a \cdot b \\[4mm]
    & =: &  ...
\end{array}
\intertext{In the group this means that ... }
\begin{array}{l@{\hspace{3mm}}c@{\hspace{3mm}}l}
a & = &  b.
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `align` and `(short)intertext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
\begin{array}{l@{\hspace{3mm}}c@{\hspace{3mm}}l}
... & := &  ... \\[4mm]
    & =: &  ... 
\end{array}
\intertext{\lipsum*[1]}      %% or \shortintertext{\lipsum*[1]} from mathtools
\begin{array}{l@{\hspace{3mm}}c@{\hspace{3mm}}l}
... & := &  ... \\[4mm]
    & =: &  ... 
\end{array}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Dealing the edited question:

You can get rid of `array` too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\h}[1]{\widehat{\bm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\he}{\ensuremath{\tfrac{1}{2}}}
\newcommand{\quat}[2]{\mathlarger{\llbracket\,} \cos{(\he#2)}, \, \sin{(\he#2)} \,\h{#1} \mathlarger{\,\rrbracket}}
\newcommand{\quatv}[1]{\mathlarger{\llbracket\,} 0, \,\h{#1} \mathlarger{\,\rrbracket}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \quatv{b} \cdot \quatv{a} & := \mathlarger{\llbracket} -\h{b}\cdot\h{a}, \, \h{b}\times\h{a} \mathlarger{\,\rrbracket} \quad \equiv \quad \mathlarger{\llbracket\,} \h{a}\cdot\h{b}, \, \h{a}\times\h{b} \mathlarger{\,\rrbracket} = \\[4mm]
 & =:  \quat{n}{\gamma}.\\
\intertext{In the group this means that ... }
 L_b \circ L_a & =:   R(\gamma \h{n}).
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this goes for long, you may add `\allowdisplaybreaks` in your preamble.

Comment: This would be perfect. In my case however the spacing doens't align. I added a MWE in my question, it uses some extra definitions, would it be possible for you to ...?

Comment: @Gerard Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with a somewhat simpler, hence more readable code. I use `mathtools` in place of `amsmath`, and `xparse`, with allows to define a `\Braket` command with a simple syntax (1 argument). I use the `coloneqq` and `eqqcolon` commands, which produce a vertically centred colon (which is not the case with `:=`). The alignment ànd numbering themselves are obtained through nesting `aligned` environments in an `align` container.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\h}[1]{\widehat{\bm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\he}{\ensuremath{\tfrac{1}{2}}}
\newcommand{\myquat}[2]{\Brackets[\big]{\cos{(\he#2)}, \sin{(\he#2)} \,\h{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myquatv}[1]{\Brackets[\big]{0,\h{#1}}}
%
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\Brackets}[1]{\llbracket}{\rrbracket}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }
 {\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{ m m }
 {#1,\,#2\mkern1.5mu}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \myquatv{b} \cdot \myquatv{a} &
\begin{aligned}[t]{}\coloneqq {}& \Brackets[\big]{-\h{b}\cdot\h{a},\h{b}\times\h{a}}\equiv  \Brackets[\big]{ \h{a}\cdot\h{b}, \h{a}\times\h{b}} = \\[4mm]
\eqqcolon {}& \myquat{n}{\gamma}.% \mathllap{}
\end{aligned}
\intertext{In the group this means that ... }
 L_b \circ L_a &\begin{aligned}[t]
 {}\eqqcolon{} &    R(\gamma \h{n}).
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not a very easy but a well-designed solution. I will look into it later on, thanks!

Comment: Is there documentation for `\begin{aligned}`? Why do you use `[t]{}` and `{}&`? What is `mathllap` for?

Comment: There is no specific documentation: fundamentally, it's the same as align*, inside another math environment. You have examples in amsmath documentation or in Herbert Voss's `mathmode`. The `[t]` option is to specify the vertical alignment with respect to the first part. It stands for "top"; the default is `[m]`, and you can choose `[b]`. You can check it changes the placement of the equation number. The pair of {} is here to ensure proper horizontal spacing on the left and the right of the = sign.